# Windows 7 putty unable to connect, but works in safemode

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty

Ok so I have been trying to get putty to run on windows 7, with very little luck.

Here is the event log from putty:

> 2012-08-09 15:23:28    Looking up host "*redacted ip*"
>
> 2012-08-09 15:23:28    Connecting to *redacted ip* port 22
>
> 2012-08-09 15:23:49    Failed to connect to *redacted ip*: Network error: Connection timed out
>
> 2012-08-09 15:23:49    Network error: Connection timed out

So far I have ensured that my routers firewall is off, turned off my firewall and anti-virus (including windows), tried various suggestions from Google including other SSH clients to no avail. I have ensured that both my router and computer are cleared for port 22. I have used netstat as well, and found nothing blocked.

The only thing that has had any success is booting windows into safe mode with networking.

That has gotten it to work but outside of that no luck. So my best guess is it is something that I am not thinking of that is blocking it. So anyone have any ideas as to what it could be? Any advice would be appreciated.

*edit*

I have used the same user in safe mode and not in safemode. The account I am using is marked as the owner of putty in taskmanager. Trying it as telnet gave no further results. Using nmap it properly shows port 22 as tcp open and ssh. I have also used filezilla to connect to a ftp server in the past with no trouble.

Comment: Can you Are you running as the same user in  safe mode and not safe mode? Have you made sure by seeing the owner of the putty.exe process in taskamanger? What about simply doing a 'telnet redacted_ip 22' from the command line to see if you can connect to the port that way? Finally, have you tried portscanning from your windows 7 machine with [nmap](http://nmap.org/),

Comment: @JustinDearing I have used the same user in safe mode and not in safemode. The account I am using is marked as the owner of putty in taskmanager. Doing a telnet gave no further results. Using nmap it properly shows port 22 as tcp open and ssh.

Comment: Oh yeah in the past I have also used FileZilla to connect to a ftp server with no trouble.

Comment: I suspect there's something *else* running that is blocking ports (which I think you've figured out). Have a look at Autoruns from SysInternals.com to see what's running on your computer.

Comment: Two things that would help rule out some options: Try connecting to another SSH server at port 22 (if available) within PuTTY with your user logged in normally. It will help us understand if it's connection specific. Then, I'd try another computer running PuTTY with the same settings, within your network connecting to the original server. It will help us determine if anything external to the original system is creating the problem.

Comment: Which Anti-Virus program is installed?  McAfee by chance? I had similar issues on friends PC, similar safe mode attempts.  Had it all disabled etc. and REFUSED to work.  As soon as I uninstalled McAfee, worked perfect. Not ideal but if you are using that AV, worth a shot.

Comment: You said that you've turned off your firewall, but you didn't say which firewall. Do you mean Windows Firewall? Also, turning off your router's firewall is normally a very bad idea unless you're in some kind of testing environment.

Comment: Are you able to establish a connection using telnet? Type `telnet <ip address> 22` at a dos prompt.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://www.fountain.com/technology/internet-wifi/ip) post I read how and what to fix.

**Posibility** : 
A previous antivirus software could have left entries in the registry and other places which weren't removed after the uninstall.

What to do?

1. Search for and remove all entries made by your previous antivirus (usually there are some tools to help you)
2. If step 1 doesn't solve the problem, try [autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to see what is running and disabling what shouldn't run at boot (restart after making changes of course)
3. Try closing processes you don't need
4. do a [limited startup](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/windows-DASH-disabling-startup-programs)
5. Run [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) after [mbam](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) to make sure you have no problems with virusses
6. Run [ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

**Disclaimer**

The tools provided are free (until you want more advanced options).    The use of the tools I recommend can do harm to your computer if you    don't really know what you're doing, so ask a professional if your    not comfortable. Uninstall all programs you won't need anymore    (especially combofix)